# Can't find image in GD (PHP)

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to put a watermark on my images, but the script can't find my watermark image. I'm doing this dynamically, so for each user there is a watermark in the watermarks folder. When trying to use this code:

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['_user_login'];

// Set the path to the image to watermark
$input_image = $targetPath.$newName; 
// Read in the text watermark image
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng("../watermarks/$username.png");
```

Nothing happens. I tried printing the user name variable and it works fine. I even tried to just print the image and it works also. But when using imagecreatefrompng, the watermark image is never found. Looking in my log I see the following error:

> Warning:
>   imagecreatefrompng(../watermarks/.png)
>   [function.imagecreatefrompng]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory

I don't get it. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you pass `'./../watermarks'.$username.'.png'`?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use:

```
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/watermarks/" . $username . ".png");
```

(You can print `dirname(__FILE__)` to check your directory structure before using this method).

Comment: Thanks, just tried that too. But still the same issue. It's weird.

Answer (score 1):

The clue's in the warning:

```
imagecreatefrompng(../watermarks/.png)
```

It's looking for a file called `.png`, so obviously your `$username = $_SESSION['_user_login'];` isn't actually returning the username, or the string isn't getting created properly.

Have you tried using braces in the string like this: `"../watermarks/{$username}.png"`? If that doesn't work then you've got a problem with your username.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution, but it doesn't work.
Funny thing is when I print it like this:
echo "$username"; in the same page I get to see the username. But when applying it to the script, it just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

$username appears to be blank. Hence, "imagecreatefrompng(../watermarks/.png)"

I'd suggest debugging starting with making sure the file path you're requesting is valid.

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['_user_login'];

// Set the path to the image to watermark
$input_image = $targetPath.$newName; 
// Read in the text watermark image
$filestring = "../watermarks/$username.png";
echo "LOOKING FOR $filestring";
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($filestring);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just tried it. When printing the filestring I can see the name of the watermark. But when applying the $watermark, the image is again not found. And in my log the name of the image is still blank. I don't know what's happening, because when I enter the name of the image manually everything works fine.

Comment: You'll have to see if you can work backwards and figure out if/when your session variable is getting set and if it's losing its value somewhere along the line. var_dump($var), print_r($var) and echo $var are your friends! :)

Comment: I did multiple times. After imagecreatefrompng and before it, I can print the username whenever I want. But there seems to be something wrong with the imagecreatefrompng function itself. It just doesn't seem to accept the variable name. Thanks tough for your suggestions.

Comment: Maybe you could try appending the string like: imagecreatefrompng("../watermarks/". $username . ".png");

Comment: Tried that too...No luck. It's weird. I'll keep looking for a solution. If I found one I'll let you all know. Thanks for your help, it's appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure it's "username" everywhere? Remember that PHP's var names are case sensitive, so username != userName != UserName != USERNAME etc....

Comment: $username would be the local scope variable in this case. $_SESSION['_user_login'] would be the one to check the casing on.

Comment: Thank you Marc. Yes I'm sure, I changed the variable different times into something else: currUser, myName etc...But it doesn't seem to care. It's driving me crazy, I've been looking for an answer for hours now. Maybe I'll just drop it if I don't find an answer...:)

Answer (score 0):

`..` is resolved from PHP's current working directory.  Presumably, this is the directory that the PHP file is currently in.

Generally, it's a better idea to resolve directories from `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` so that they are absolute* directories rather than relying on nothing doing a `chdir` before your file is opened.

```
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/watermarks/$username.png");
```

*For a given definition of absolute.

Comment: Now that it's been pointed out that `$username` is blank, I'm still leaving this here, as it's still good advice.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to change anything. The name of the image is still ".png". Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Well the $username variable is blank according to that error. Do a var_dump($_SESSION) in your script to double check your are properly storing the _user_login variable.

Also I would suggest using curly braces when putting variables in strings.

```
$watermark = imagecratefrompng("../watermarks/{$username}.png");
```

This will make it easy to see your variables and prevent php from using the wrong variable name.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I just did a var_dump($_SESSION) and I can clearly see my login name and the rest of the SESSION. The weird thing is I can print the username before and after the script. But it just doesn't work when I apply the imagecreatefrompng to it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything but for some reason the SESSION variable just doesn't work in the imagecreatefrompng function.

To solve this I just post the username as a hidden variable. This seems to work fine for the moment.

Thanks everyone for the help. It's appreciated.

mw